# Token expired Exception - AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I have an application which receives a JWT security token from another application. My application then decodes the token and then using Cognito APIs fetches additional information (for that cognito user) from the cognito pool. The first few minutes the application works fine and serves requests as expected. However I start getting below exception :

```
022-10-03 08:04:18.023 ERROR 1 — [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderException: The security token included in the request is expired (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ExpiredTokenException; Request ID: e83f4f85-a297-4086-b1e4-27be20ef08fc; Proxy: null)] with root cause
com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidp.model.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderException: The security token included in the request is expired (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ExpiredTokenException; Request ID: e83f4f85-a297-4086-b1e4-27be20ef08fc; Proxy: null)
```

Even a fresh token created with an expiry of 1 hour still gives the same exception. Below is how I'm creating a cognito client and doing an AdminGetUserRequest from the Cognito pool (I'm using a ECS Container role to extract credentials) :

```
AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper();
AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoClient = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard().
                        withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1).
                        withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(provider.getCredentials())).
                        build();

// AdminGetUserResult - this is where the exception is thrown 
AdminGetUserResult adminUserResult = provider.adminGetUser(
                    new AdminGetUserRequest()
                            .withUserPoolId(cognitoPoolDto.getCognitoPoolId())
                            .withUsername(cognitoPoolDto.getUserName()));
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong since the application works fine for a few requests. I know it's something to do with the way the credentials are being used , since previously I used the AWS Keys as Environment variables and only recently I've switched to Container Role provided credentials. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the time on the machine properly synchronized?

Comment: @stdunbar yep it's syncronized.